# Pandas concat on multiindex columns based on level's name

Tags: python, pandas

I am seeing a wierd behavior from pandas, maybe it's just me but I am expecting a different result from what I am getting.

so assuming that I have a multi-index dataframe such has:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(index=list('abcde'), data={'A': range(5), 'B': range(5)})
df_first = pd.concat({'ticker1': df, 'ticker2': df, 'ticker3': df}, axis=1)
df_first.columns = df_first.columns.rename(('ticker', 'variables'))

df_first
Out[91]: 
ticker    ticker1    ticker2    ticker3   
variables       A  B       A  B       A  B
a               0  0       0  0       0  0
b               1  1       1  1       1  1
c               2  2       2  2       2  2
d               3  3       3  3       3  3
e               4  4       4  4       4  4
```

and a second dataframe with the same level's name but reversed such has:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=list('abcde'), data={'ticker1': range(5), 'ticker2': range(5)})
df_sec = pd.concat({'C': df2, 'D': df2, 'E': df2}, axis=1)
df_sec.columns = df_sec.columns.rename(('variables', 'ticker'))

df_sec
Out[93]: 
variables       C               D               E        
ticker    ticker1 ticker2 ticker1 ticker2 ticker1 ticker2
a               0       0       0       0       0       0
b               1       1       1       1       1       1
c               2       2       2       2       2       2
d               3       3       3       3       3       3
e               4       4       4       4       4       4
```

as you can see the levels have the same names but are reversed. when I concat those 2 dataframe on the `axis = 1`, it mixes up my columns:

```
pd.concat([df_first, df_sec], axis=1)
Out[94]: 
ticker    ticker1    ticker2    ticker3          C               D               E        
variables       A  B       A  B       A  B ticker1 ticker2 ticker1 ticker2 ticker1 ticker2
a               0  0       0  0       0  0       0       0       0       0       0       0
b               1  1       1  1       1  1       1       1       1       1       1       1
c               2  2       2  2       2  2       2       2       2       2       2       2
d               3  3       3  3       3  3       3       3       3       3       3       3
e               4  4       4  4       4  4       4       4       4       4       4       4
```

I know I can swap levels first and get the expected result such has:

```
pd.concat([df_first, df_sec.swaplevel(0, 1, 1)], axis=1)
Out[95]: 
ticker    ticker1    ticker2    ticker3    ticker1 ticker2 ticker1 ticker2 ticker1 ticker2
variables       A  B       A  B       A  B       C       C       D       D       E       E
a               0  0       0  0       0  0       0       0       0       0       0       0
b               1  1       1  1       1  1       1       1       1       1       1       1
c               2  2       2  2       2  2       2       2       2       2       2       2
d               3  3       3  3       3  3       3       3       3       3       3       3
e               4  4       4  4       4  4       4       4       4       4       4       4
```

but is there a way to `concat` based on the level names directly?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of anything that doesn't manipulate the columns index in some way.  But this gets close to what you asked for.  Namely, it operates on level name.

```
ln = 'variables'
pd.concat([df_first.stack(ln), df_sec.stack(ln)]).unstack(ln)
```

[image]

OR

```
ln = 'ticker'
pd.concat([df_first.stack(ln), df_sec.stack(ln)], axis=1).unstack(ln)
```

[image]