# Appending two dataframes with multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, each with a multiindex.  The multiindex levels share names, but are in a different order.  When I append or concat, I would expect pandas to line up the indices just like it aligns index-less columns before appending.  Is there a function or an argument I can pass to append or concat to get this to work in the way I desire (and that I think ought to be standard)?

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Name':['Bob','Ann','Sally'], 'Acct':['Savings','Savings','Checking'], 'Value':[101,102,103]})
df1 = df1.set_index(['Name','Acct'])
print(df1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Acct':['Savings','Savings','Checking'], 'Name':['Bob','Ann','Sally'], 'Value':[201,202,203]})
df2 = df2.set_index(['Acct','Name'])
print(df2)

print(df1.append(df2))
print(pd.concat([df1,df2]))


               Value
Name  Acct
Bob   Savings     101
Ann   Savings     102
Sally Checking    103

                Value
Acct     Name
Savings  Bob      201
         Ann      202
Checking Sally    203

                   Value
Name     Acct
Bob      Savings     101
Ann      Savings     102
Sally    Checking    103
Savings  Bob         201
         Ann         202
Checking Sally       203

                   Value
Name     Acct
Bob      Savings     101
Ann      Savings     102
Sally    Checking    103
Savings  Bob         201
         Ann         202
Checking Sally       203
```

As you can see, after appending or concatenating, my combined index appears to show that, for example, "Sally" is an account, not a name.  I'm aware that if I put the index levels in the same order when setting index, I'll get what I want, and that I could reset the index on the frames to align them, but I'm hoping there's a more intuitive way to get the indices to align on name, not on position.

Comment: Hi, have you already tried applying `pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel` to one of the dataframes before concatenating them? See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html for more details.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40243425/pandas-concat-on-multiindex-columns-based-on-levels-name

Comment: Why do you want to have multiple lines with the same index?

Comment: @IanThompson sorry, my example was a little more artificial than intended.  I don't want that situation.  I should have made the "accts" different in the second df.

Comment: I don't think it get's more intuitive than `swaplevel`. Pandas cares about the level of indices in a multiindex, not the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat of a work around, you can `reset_index` on both data sets, `concat` them, then `set_index`:

```
print(pd.concat([
    df1.reset_index(),
    df2.reset_index()
], sort=False).set_index([
    'Name',
    'Acct'
]))

                Value
Name  Acct           
Bob   Savings     101
Ann   Savings     102
Sally Checking    103
Bob   Savings     201
Ann   Savings     202
Sally Checking    203
```

Though I'm not sure why you would want to have multiple rows with the same index...